# html from asp.net mvc3 not rendered properly in jquery ui dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-views

I am having a jquery ui dialog which takes html from a partial view from an asp.net mvc3 controller.

The jquery call is very simple:

```
 $(result).appendTo("#vierge");
 $("#vierge").dialog();
```

where the result of the partialView is as follow:

```
<p><span style="background-color: yellow; ">&nbsp;test test</span></p>
```

When I make an alert of the result I am having this:
[image]

But the dialog display nothing, for you what could be wrong with my code ?

Thanks alot for your help

ps: I am trying to load the dialog another way:

```
        $(dialogDiv).load(href)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
            });
```

the dialog open ok, but it display plain html code instead of the rendered html, [such as this](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/VSa9k/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing $ sign in the first line, it should be like this:

```
$(result).appendTo("#vierge");
$("#vierge").dialog();
```

if you don't need to append result but only display it in a dialog box, you can use this code:

```
$('#vierge').html(result);
$("#vierge").dialog();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, in fact I have put the $sign, miss it when copy and past for the question. I tried all the codes above, the second display the html code but not the html rendering. I am wondering if it may come that as I am storing all the html code in the database, when the partialView retrieve the codes, initially (<p><span style="background-color: yellow; ">&nbsp;test test</span></p>), it transforms all the <,>, special caracters to &lt, &gt,...which can be the problem...how would the dialog transform back all special caracters to html...

Comment: What strange is when I append html code in the $('#vierge').html(*****htmlCodeHere*****); it works perfectly, with the html rendered but not when dynamically getting result from actionController, it display plain html codes...

Comment: could you paste in code responsible for ajax call? try creating a new partial view with static html code, and load this into the dialog. Did you check what is stored in DB? it may be that html code in DB is encoded or it gets encoded somewhere between DB and View.
If it is really that html code that comes from DB is encoded, try to run this method on it:
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;")
before you put it into the partial view.

Comment: Hi Maciej, I finally end up with returning the results as Json from the actionController, it works perfectly, I don' t know why through the partialView it does not rendered properly. When I will have some time, I will test your HttpUtility.HtmlDecode function (by the way I have learnt something new). Thanks again for your help